# How would I set this up?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Basically I want a webpage where when it loads it shows the sign up screen. But then when the user scrolls down they'll see more stuff. I want to "mask" the bottom part so that then the user doesn't see it if they don't scroll down.I'm not sure what I should Google to find results. How would I go about on setting this up? Would I use margins? Its in HTML and CSS by the way.

Comment: Find out how big the window is, then render your output to be "below the edge of the screen".

Comment: @Floris Through JavaScript?

Comment: Sure - see http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header">header</div>
 <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="other">I am out</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#header
{
    height: 111px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmTHn/)

Comment: Very nice - good to include the JSFiddle demo for the skeptics!